# Summing up the total number of times a field value appears in a table

Tags: php, mysql

In the table `comment` below, `comment.comment` can be the same term for multiple rows.

For each unique term `comment.comment`, how can I count the number of times it appears, and then order the query below by the `comment.comment` term descending by frequency?

```
$query2 = "SELECT comment.comment, login.username
FROM comment
LEFT JOIN login ON comment.loginid=login.loginid
WHERE submissionid=$submissionid
ORDER BY comment.points DESC 
LIMIT 100";
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the GROUP BY statement, you can group all the records with the same value for a specified field.  This will give the top 10 repeated comments and their counts.

```
SELECT comment.comment, count(*) as count
FROM comment
GROUP BY comment.comment
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`COUNT()`](http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp), [`GROUP BY`](http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), [aliasing](http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp), [`ORDER BY`](http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp).